# Shouldn't Android Phone GPS be more accurate

Tags: android, gps

I am making an app to monitor my GPS then to do some calculations and found the conversion to go from degrees to meters to be 1deg = 111325m.  When getting the GPS coordinates on my phone it comes in at 8 places after the decimal.  So .00000001 *111325 = .001m , so shouldn't my phones GPS technically be able to at least be accurate to fractions of a meter?  Anyone know where my thinking is going wrong or what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

> so shouldn't my phones GPS technically be able to at least be accurate to fractions of a meter?

No.

> Anyone know where my thinking is going wrong or what I am missing?

Mathematical operations like division can introduce many decimal places that are above and beyond what is supported by the underlying science. The value of pi, for example, has infinite decimal places; this does not mean that you know the circumference of an orange with infinite accuracy.

Comment: You can be as accurate as you can measure the orange.  Its our ability to measure that limits our accuracy.  The GPS coordinate is given to me with that many digits so even if I take 2 digits away and take .000001 * 111325 to match the accuracy of the conversion ratio it still gives less than a meter.  So there has to be another reason other than the calculations limit the accuracy.

Comment: @user912620: "You can be as accurate as you can measure the orange" -- correct. And GPS fixes will be as accurate as they can measure your location. Your question, however, indicates that you believe that the mere existence of numbers to the right of the decimal place indicates the level of accuracy, which is incorrect. "So there has to be another reason other than the calculations limit the accuracy" -- plenty, none of which has anything to do with software development (let alone Android) and therefore is off-topic for StackOverflow. Read up on how GPS works, such as on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two things:

1) The delivered resolution of the latitude, longitude coordinate representation variable in the API:  this can be a double or float.
and
2) The physical accuracy of the GPS position, compard to real position.

(There is a third thing: the resoultion of th ecoordinate inside the GPS receiver, which in the past was a 4 byte int, giving a may of 3cm, today 8 byte longs are used.)

GPS receivers today have a typically accuracy of 3 - 6m.

About your 8 places of decimal: 7 places after decimal latitude/longitude can be transformed to a 4 byte integer, which gives 3cm resolution. So chances are high, that some  internal API or the GPS CHIP uses a 4 byte int to represent the coordinates.

However with some tricks you can reach fractions of meters, like you want.
This can be achieved by avergaging many  positions while the phone does not move.

On iphone this does not work, because the API supressed to deliver positions while standing still, but maybe thats works on some android phones.